# Show Images From Flick in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

**API :**

```
"data": [    
 {
  "accrediationsId": 1,
   "imageURL": "<a data-flickr-embed=\"true\"  href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/152241238@N02/25515548558/in/photostream/\" title=\"1\">
   <img src=\"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4592/25515548558_0cb257389b_o.jpg\" width=\"266\" height=\"79\" alt=\"1\"></a>
   <script async src=\"//embedr.flickr.com/assets/client-code.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>"
 },
 {
  "accrediationsId": 2,
  "imageURL": "<a data-flickr-embed=\"true\"  href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/152241238@N02/25515548508/in/photostream/\" title=\"2\">
  <img src=\"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4728/25515548508_16ab9d0cb4_o.jpg\" width=\"266\" height=\"79\" alt=\"2\"></a>
  <script async src=\"//embedr.flickr.com/assets/client-code.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>"
 },
```

**HTML CODE :**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="Affiliation in 
            getAffiliationData">
            {{Affiliation.imageURL}}
</div>
```

Need to show Images from flikr in html page by using angular js. Is that possible to get image path directly from flikr api and show in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double braces are not used for binding html content, they are used for rendering text, to render html you can use this "ng-bind-html"
Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="Affiliation in getAffiliationData">
   <div ng-bind-html="Affiliation.imageURL"></div>
</div>
```

you will need to inject this [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

here is the [demo link](https://plnkr.co/edit/OhC21kzA7dWeExuQhXj6?p=preview)

Comment: @RajGujrathi i added a link for the demo, please try it

Comment: Thank u Soo much Abdullah S Ahmad Sir

Answer (score 1):

Use **image** element with `ng-src`

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="Affiliation in 
            getAffiliationData">
     <img ng-src="{{Affiliation.imageURL}}"> 
</div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app =angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.getAffiliationData = [
 {
            "accrediationsId": 1,
            "imageURL": "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4592/25515548558_0cb257389b_o.jpg"
 },
 {
            "accrediationsId": 2,
            "imageURL": "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4728/25515548508_16ab9d0cb4_o.jpg"
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="Affiliation in 
            getAffiliationData"  ng-click="setClickedRow(user)">
     <img ng-src="{{Affiliation.imageURL}}">   
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: the problem is with your image urls you need to have a valid url as show above